# How to rotate zookeeper daemon/console log

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-zookeeper, logrotate

On my zookeeper log4j configuration, I have logger for console and rolling file.

I ran my zookeeper using systemctl.

In zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh, there's this line
`_ZOO_DAEMON_OUT="$ZOO_LOG_DIR/zookeeper.out"`
which I assume is where the console logger for zookeeper.

One day the zookeeper.out got too big, and to clean it up, I need to stop zookeeper, delete zookeeper.out, and start zookeeper.

Question: Is there a way to rotate the zookeeper.out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `CONSOLE` log appender from your log4j properties.
Please check out [this post on Cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Zookeeper-log-file-not-rotated/td-p/134777).

Just switch to `ROLLINGFILE` instead.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ROLLINGFILE
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=${zookeeper.log.dir}/zookeeper.log 
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Comment: does the log printed to console have the exact same information as the one printed to logfile? I was thinking about just removing the console logger, but I am kinda afraid that there's some information that will be missed out on

Comment: @SillySally yes, the information is the same. appenders define how and where the logs will be written, but the logs itself are the same: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender, https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender